# correct jquery code format

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to correct this format, and I don't know how to fix it. I just want only to give set the "title" to img tag as the filename in my html output.

here's the code, so bear with me about this output.

```
var imgName = $bxNextImage.attr("title");
$title.text( '<img src='imgName' width='' height='' alt=''>' );
```

Thanks to someone who can help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both ' and " quotation marks:

```
var imgName = $bxNextImage.attr("title");
$title.html( '<img src="' + imgName + '" width="" height="" alt=""/>' );
```

I changed from `.text()` to `.html()` because `.text()` would not render an image object, but rather just the plain text.